# List View Tools missing in SharePoint Designer 2010 when viewing a list

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, list, web-part, sub-site

I am trying to do something fairly simple in SharePoint 2010. I have a Link (Links object) on a subsite. I want to show this list in a parent site. I found several links that show how to do this, such as  http://mroffice365.com/2012/01/sharepoint-display-a-list-or-library-from-subsite-to-the-top-level-site/

Basically, they say to open the list in SharePoint designer, and export it as a web part. However, when I click the "All Links" view in the "Views" section, I should be getting a "List View Tools" tab at the top. However, I do not. It displays the code for the page and shows a "Code View Tools" tab at the top. Why am I stuck in this code view mode, and how do I get the regular List View Tools tab back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After restarting SharePoint Designer, I was able to get into Design View. I could then click on white space on the page and the List View Tools tab showed at the top.